# How to make my app unmovable from pc to another

Tags: python, windows

I created an application with python that i will be selling in the next few days, however I don't want anyone that buys it able to share it with other people as it is paid so everyone that wants the app should pay. i'm not finding a way of doing it, I hope you help me to do so!

can you recommend any tool/framework/method that will help me to achieve this.
I tried to search and wasn't able to find a good way.

I am using kivy for GUI and made with pure python.
**Note: I will compile the app only for PCs and not mobile phones**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any copy-protection mechanism you invent will likely inconvenience paying users and a determined hacker will ultimately break it.  So consider the trade-offs between making it ultra-hard to copy and the value of the application itself.  The easiest thing you could do is package your app for the Windows Store (or Steam) and just sell it there. Disclaimer - I have no idea what it would take to ship a python app through the store. But you could look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter)

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do that would be to have some sort of launcher that someone who paid for the app could type their credentials in and would pass along their windows username to you then pass that username over the internet to you and make it the first thing python checks before processing and have it check that it is the same username

lastly using [pyminifier] https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/ to make your code look unreadable you should either embed python in another language https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html or if that is too much of a hassle compile your username specific script into python bytecode but know that python bytecode alone isn't enough to stop anyone skilled in python from using a github script to get your source code minus actual variables and comments and sometimes **doc**